# How to run "go vet" on an entire project including internal packages?

Tags: go

I would like to run `go vet` on my entire Go project. The project follows the [Standard Go Project Layout](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout/) and has a number of "internal" packages.

```
project
|- go.mod
|- main.go
|- internal
|  |- package1
|  |- foo/pack
|  |- bar/pack
|- vendor
   |- github.com
      |- foo
         | bar
```

How do I run `go vet` against all of the code? Ideally, this would be just *my* code and exclude the `vendor` directory.

Here's what doesn't work:

- `go vet` - Covers just the top-level `main.go`

Comment: Note that there's rarely a need to run `go vet` on it's own any longer, since it's run as part of `go test`.

Comment: My question asked about `go vet`, and the linked duplicate is about `go test`. If `go test` invokes `vet`, that's great, but nothing I ran across while searching for this indicated as much.

Comment: `go test` and `go vet` are both invocations of the same `go` command, and will parse the arguments and expand the wildcards the same way

Answer (score 14):

Like many commands, `go vet` runs against a list of *packages*. Packages can be listed in a variety of ways. See [`go help packages`](https://godoc.org/cmd/go#hdr-Package_lists_and_patterns).

This command will do what we want:

```
go vet ./...
```

You can confirm the list of packages being vetted by using `go list` instead:

```
go list ./...
```

Specifically, it leverage these syntactic tricks:

- > An import path that is a rooted path or that begins with a `.` or `..` element is interpreted as a file system path and denotes the package in that directory.
- > An import path is a pattern if it includes one or more `...` wildcards, each of which can match any string, including the empty string and strings containing slashes.
- > `./...` does not match packages in subdirectories of `./vendor` or `./mycode/vendor`

Comment: This is a slightly different than what your original question asks -- an "entire project including internal packages" is simply `go vet ./...`. The vendor directory is excluded from wildcards.

Comment: Thanks @JimB. I had originally consulted older documentation that did not include that fact. I've simplified my answer accordingly.